# Automatically rename .JPG file-extensions on Linux server

Tags: linux, jpeg, rename, watch

i have a node application which displays images in the browser via a socket connection.
The client delivers images in a deliver folder which is synced via BitTorrent Sync with the server. 
However the client's camera is outputting images with an uppercase .JPG extension. The application can only work with lowercase extensions.

Is there a way to watch a folder for uppercase extensions on the server and rename the files automatically to lowercase ones directly?

Comment: sure, there's APIs to watch for filesystem changes and trigger things when those events occur.

Comment: A) It's bad application design only working with a special case of characters. B) As @MarcB mentioned there is [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en).